# Nesting routes in Angular UI Router and displaying on the first ui view

Tags: angular-ui-router

I have a first Ui-View called A that dynamically loads a page fine.

I then put another link (or route) in the page A, however Ui Route wants a ui-view in page A.

How can I go back to the orginal ui-view, and place page B in that instead of A's?

Im trying to have a nested route go into the orginal UI-View instead of a new one.

Answer (score 0):

By naming UI-View's you can define where the router will put the view.